# ORA-00936 error:insert query is not working in procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

```
execute immediate 'insert into ' || rec.destinationtable || '(' || rec.destinationcolumn || ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1 || ') values ( select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||' ,select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||')';
```

it is showing "ORA-00936: missing expression" error in ORACLE 11g

Answer (score 0):

You should use brackets  when your are using select from multiple tables

Try

```
execute immediate 'insert into ' || rec.destinationtable || '(' || rec.destinationcolumn || ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1 || ') values ( (select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||' ),(select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||'))';
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
execute immediate 'insert into ' || rec.destinationtable ||
'(' || rec.destinationcolumn || ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1 || ')
( select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||' ,
select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable||')';
```

if you are specifying the cloumn names to which insertion is to be done, omit the 'values' phrase in the query.

Comment: I've removed the downvote after reflection. Your answer isn't quite right though - the subquery "(select x from y, select z from a)" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
     'insert into '
  || rec.destinationtable
  || '(' || rec.destinationcolumn
  || ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1
  || ') values ( select '
  || rec.sourcecolumn
  || ' from '
  || rec.sourcetable
  || ' ,select '
  || rec.sourcecolumn
  || ' from '
  || rec.sourcetable || ')';
```

If you execute the above expression, you get something like this:

```
insert into [destinationtable]
  ([destinationcolumn]
  ,[destinationcolumn1]
  )
values (
  select [sourcecolumn] from [sourcetable]
 ,select [sourcecolumn] from [sourcetable]
)
```

which is not a valid insert statement.

You are using the VALUES clause and supplying two expressions, but those expressions are themselves subqueries, so they need to be surrouned by parentheses, e.g.:

```
insert into [destinationtable]
  ([destinationcolumn]
  ,[destinationcolumn1]
  )
values (
   ( select [sourcecolumn] from [sourcetable] )
 , ( select [sourcecolumn] from [sourcetable] )
)
```

So you need to include them in your expression, e.g.:

```
  execute immediate
    'insert into '
  || rec.destinationtable
  || '(' || rec.destinationcolumn
  || ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1
  || ') values ( ( select '
  || rec.sourcecolumn
  || ' from '
  || rec.sourcetable
  || ' ) , ( select '
  || rec.sourcecolumn
  || ' from '
  || rec.sourcetable || ' ) )';
```

To make the code somewhat clearer you could do this:

```
DECLARE
  source1 VARCHAR2(1000);
  source2 VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN

  source1 := 'select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable;

  source2 := 'select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable;

  execute immediate
    'insert into ' || rec.destinationtable
  ||   '(' || rec.destinationcolumn
  ||   ',' || rec.destinationcolumn1
  || ') values ('
  ||   '(' || source1 || ')'
  || ', (' || source2 || ')'
  || ')';

END;
```